# SAS program runs interactively but not as batch file - issues authorizing access to drives

Tags: batch-file, sas

I have a SAS code which works flawlessly when I first open the program and run the code interactively. However, if I try to run it as a batch file or execute it from the command prompt using the -sysin option, it doesn't run and I don't know why.

Part of the reason might be that when I run SAS, I receive this dialog box which I need to manually close:

[Screencap 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMrFj.png)

When I try to choose the option "Do not show this dialog box again" it doesn't work, and it shows the dialog every time I open SAS. This may be because my registry and profile files are corrupted:

[Screencap2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2YsF.png)

Would this be the reason why? If I run the program interactively after closing the dialog box, the program run just fine. I tried to follow some steps to repair the registry and profile files, but it didn't work. Is that what I should focus on, or is there likely another reason it won't run in batch?

Thanks for your input!

edit: I was able to get the program to run from the batch file, but I get the following errors about permissions in the log file:

```
ERROR: Insufficient authorization to access //destinationonselecteddrive
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: PROCEDURE PRINTTO used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

I do not have these issues with insufficient authorization when I run the program interactively, only in batch mode. Could it be a metadata issue?

Comment: I think if you run the program batch using a different SAS profile, it should run fine. You probably want to create a custom CONFIG file to point to the different SAS profile. I do it all the time.

Comment: What does `it doesn't run` mean?  Nothing happens?  Or you get an error?  The dialog box bit is irrelevant (that won't have any impact on a non-interactive session) but the other part (the config files) could be.  Any chance you have multiple SAS sessions open at once?

Comment: And what *exaclty* happens when you run as a batch file?  Do you get at least a brief `sas` popup?

Comment: I made an edit to my original post. I asked it to produce a log file and it says I don't have authorization to access the drives indicated in the SAS code. However, this only happens in batch mode. When I open SAS and run the code, it runs fine and I don't get any errors regarding access to those drives.

Comment: How are you running it in batch mode?

Comment: Either directly from the command line or from a .bat file, either way the text is the same: 

    "E:\sasdirectory\sasfile.exe -sysin E:\mydirectory\myprogram.sas -log E:\mydirectory\mylogfile .txt"

Answer (score 0):

You have to check with which profile your batch is running. When run interactively it may (and it will normally) use a different profile than the one you are using while running interactively. That means different user and password. You can check in the management console (or ask your administrator to check).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds most likely like there is a problem with the user profile. At my old job I ran into problem with the profile when I ran concurrent SAS sessions. I had to set my user profile to read only using the RSASUSER option ([SAS instruction here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/67962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0npwfu9o7rvtun1f8f4ztpug83z.htm)). If that is not the issue try creating a new profile catalog in a new location and then adding the -SASUSER option with the new location ([SAS info on how to do that](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/67962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0bmj7wjme32ayn1h4wim7trkhp6.htm#n11ywe70uyws6hn1t5u0nsj1asa8)).